# Quagga, OSPF, announcing inactive tunnel

Tags: routing, openvpn, ospf, quagga

I have a 3 node network with OSPF Quagga running on each of them.

Each node connected with p2p, OpenVPN:
http://vetal.ca/Download/img/Network_loop.png

(Will embed picture here when have reputation > 10)

pfSense has two OpenVPN clients, with ip 10.0.1.2 and 10.0.2.2, going to server 1 and 2 respectively.

Now, connection C (10.0.2.1 - 10.0.2.2) dies. What happens is, network is adapted and pfSence receives OSPF update that (10.0.2.1 - 10.0.2.2) is accessible via [B->A] route, instead of just [C]
pfSense has information about 10.0.2.1 - 10.0.2.2 link and knows it exists 2 hops away.

Result is, when OpenVPN, C-tunnel client is trying to restart, it can't. Since it can't assign ip address which is in routing table:

Quote

```
/sbin/ifconfig ovpnc1 10.0.2.1 - 10.0.2.2 mtu 1500 netmask 255.255.255.255 up
 FreeBSD ifconfig failed: external program exited with error status: 1
```

Manual call tells

```
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Address already in use
```

Which way I can prevent this? Can I probe the dead link somehow? So, if tunnel C dies, Server 2 removes it and not advertise

I already tried link-detect, it shows link as up on Server 2 (OpenVPN listening side) anyway:

```
interface tun1
 description VPS link C
 link-detect
 ipv6 nd suppress-ra
!
```

Shall it be separated with zones, e.g. A - backbone, ? Or is there a tcp-probe inset to quagga to tell if link is pingable?

If there is a probe, it will help to deal with another case:

On the picture above, if segment A is down. Traffic will be rerouted via pfSense (B->C instead of A) and stuck there. Since traffic is disabled (intentionally) from passing between tunnels by pfSense.

I am new to dynamic routing and believe there is a standard way to deal with this loop

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working solution on pfSense forum:

https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=91361.msg506747#msg506747

So, rule of the thumb, for a client end.

for each VPN-ospf endpoint, disable acceptance for "my(endpoint) IP/32". So, it won't come from other end.

E.g., in case on the diagram, it will look like this in zebra.conf:

```
password <my-password>
log syslog

ip prefix-list ACCEPTFILTER deny 10.0.1.2/32
ip prefix-list ACCEPTFILTER deny 10.0.2.2/32
ip prefix-list ACCEPTFILTER permit any
route-map ACCEPTFILTER permit 10
match ip address prefix-list ACCEPTFILTER
ip protocol ospf route-map ACCEPTFILTER
```